# Android Things: GPIO button/switch handler only responds once

Tags: android-things, intel-edison

I am working through the tutorial for the Android Things SDK and I have the following set up:

[image: pictures showing the Edison and its connections]

I hooked up the hardware via the Android Things SDK and have a working handler for the button/switch working **but** it only works once. After that I need to restart the board to get the handler to fire again.

I'm new to this stuff so not really sure how to diagnose it. The SDK isn't reporting any errors and restarting the android app will re-print out all the available GPIO and messages I have so I know the board is "frozen", but that input will not respond again until I restart the entire board.

Any help or explanation appreciated.

**Setup:**
Intel Edison. Red = power, black = ground. 10k resistor is connected to power (sorry for the photo).

Comment: Share your code as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. It turns out the problem was configuration related. I was using a 10k ohm resistor and I should have been using a 330 ohm one. The issue, in my opinion, stemmed from some decently confusing images in the Android Things "Getting Started" guide and the fact that the Raspberry Pi is more popular (so the instructions were geared toward that specific configuration).

Thanks to everyone who replied. I figure this is at least useful in case someone who's super new to this (like me) makes the same mistake.

Comment: +1 for coming back to record the solution. Really, this is an electronics problem (threshold voltages and input currents), but as you say, it might help someone.

Comment: This is probably *not* the answer, but merely a random coincidence of something you changed at the same time as something that was the answer.  Even if the 10K resistor were insufficient, a 330 ohm one is probably far in excess of need.